# Grid row height ratio based on content

Tags: wpf

I have a grid with two rows. In each row there is a ListView.
In first row there is 100 items and in second row there is 500 items.
This will not fit on screen, so I would like to have scrollbars shown at each ListView (no problem) and row heights should be in ratio of heights of ListViews. Like 1* and 5* but I don't know in advance how big these ListBoxes will be.

**Note:** each item may have different size, so I would like to use actual ListBox height instead of items count

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> <!-- keep ratio of rows based on Listbox Heights -->
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- 100 items -->
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- 500 items -->
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Height,ElementName=ListBox1}"/>
        <!-- keep ratio of rows based on Listbox Heights -->
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Height,ElementName=ListBox2}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ListBox1">
        <!-- 100 items -->
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListBox2">
        <!-- 500 items -->
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

if you have a more complex scenarios, you can use a converter.

Comment: This won't work. This will set absolute height not * ratio. I have used "StarConverter" but it won't work either because Height or ActualHeight of Lisbox is what is shown on screen not height of all elements in Listbox :(